# Is this solution unique?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f(p)$ be a Lebesgue measurable function on $p\in (0,1)$ satisfying
$$
    f^2(p(1-p))= f(p^2)\times f((1-p)^2).
$$
$f(p)=\lambda p^{\alpha}$, for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, is a solution.

Question:
Is this the only solution  of the equation?

Comment: In principle, $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ can be different depending on whether $p$ is algebraic or transcendental since the equation never relates function values at algebraic numbers to those at transcendental numbers. You may want a more restrictive condition on the function to rule these things out.

Comment: If you substitute $g(x)=\ln f(e^x)$, then the whole thing turns to a Cauchy-style equation. Does that (and relevant properties of the Cauchy equation) solve the problem? (I haven't got time to look into this.)

Comment: By $f^2(x)$, do you mean $f\big(f(x)\big)$ or $f(x)^2=f(x)\cdot f(x)$?

Comment: The latter: $f^2=f\times f$.